# NLP: how do you determine the polarity of a certain word?

Tags: nlp, nltk

Sorry for the vague nature of this question, but I don't even know the proper NLP terminology to search constructively.

Basically what I'm attempting to do is to determine whether a word (usually an adjective or a noun) is "confirmed" by its context, or "negated." (Apologies for potential misuse of terminology)

The application is one step of a larger process that parses through a large body of user reviews, and uses keyword frequency to determine certain aspects of a product. However, certain keywords may either apply or not apply depending on the context.

As an example, when looking for a keyword "flimsy", two possible contexts are:

A) "The product felt flimsy in my hands and fell apart within days" --> keyword confirmed

B) "The build quality was very solid and not at all flimsy like its competitors" --> keyword negated

Note that this is different from the sentiment analysis of the phrase; the purpose is not to determine whether or not the opinion is positive or negative, but rather if a word is applicable in context or not.

Is there any standard methodology or technique to achieve this?

Comment: I believe walking each sentence left to right, starting in "positive" mode and switching to negative when a word such as "not" is seen, is the baseline approach to this problem, and works surprisingly well for English. Can't recall what the problem is called, though, probably "negation scope detection" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks -- that's a pretty interesting (and straightforward) method. I might give that a shot.